# MIC28515 overheating with high input voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck, switching-regulator, overheat

I've designed this MIC28515 buck regulator based on the manufacturer schematic reference. I'm planning to run it at 70VIn

[image: MIC28515 regulator]

I'm doing the tests with @ 5V 2A load Temp(Amb) = 20C.

When I set a VIn of 20V the IC's temperature shoots up to 68C for some reason.

For reference the temperature at VIn = 15V is just around 46C which seems somewhat normal.

Any suggestions to what could cause that phenomenon?

The manufacturer also claims to achieve 5A@50C with this IC.

My Design

[image: Mine]

Ref design:

[image: RefD]

Scope output @VIn = 20V:

[image: Scope]

Comment: Any oscillations happening? How is the PCB layed out compared to the reference design?

Comment: Edited the question with everything

Comment: Also interested in knowing how was the inductor determined because with the question they offer in the datasheet my results are off...

Comment: Section 5.4 of the [MIC28515](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MIC28515-75V-5A-Hyper-Speed-Control-Synch-DC-DC-Buck-Regulator-with-External-Mode-Control-DS20005762C.pdf) describe inductor selection, I assume you've followed that and arrived at an appropriate value. Is the freq as expected? Is Vdd 5.0v? Page 28, looks like they want lots of vias under the chip for heat-sinking, did you do similar?